How to attribute the images I have used on my website?
There are pictures on my website that are not mine and I dont know how should I indicate the source. Also I should write them an email? Or if someone know how this is works I would be very grateful if you could describe in the comment for me. Im little bit afraid that the pictures owners will sue me so thats the reason that I asked you guys how should I do that.
Here is what I found one of the pictures owner Terms of Use part: "You may link back to this website or a certain page provided your website does not contain content that is considered illegal or harmful." That means I can use it just needs to create some link back to their main site?

You could send them a polite email asking...

Pertaining to images, you want to make sure to pay close attention to the attribution rules for each image. Some licenses might give you free reign with the image and require no attribution while others, even if you alter the original, will still require you to include attribution.
Most images and software are licensed/protected through Creative Commons Licenses. Depending on the license used, it will require you as the "user" to attribute back to the original owner/creator.
Whatever platform you got the image from should tell you how to attribute (or if it is even required). Most of the time, this will require a caption stating who the original owner of the image is.
